# Запуск функции каждую минуту Golang

Tags: golang, время

Есть простая функция на Go, например:

```
func hello() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World!")
}
```

Как сделать так, что бы это функция вызывалась через определенный промежуток времени, например, каждую минуту (Не прибегая к cron)?

Comment: https://github.com/aubm/interval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовать пакет `time`. Нужно добавить в вашу функцию задержку и бесконечный цикл и запускать ее в отдельной go-рутине:

```
package main

import (
  "time"
  "fmt"
)

func hello() {
  for {
    fmt.Println("Hello World!")
    time.Sleep(60 * time.Second)
  }
}

func main() {
  go hello()
}
```